# Load a page and fill the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript, I am trying to write a script that opens a window and then fills the form and submits it.
The code I have written just loads the page but it is not filling the form what is wrong with my code and how can I correct it?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Popup</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function LoadTextBox(){
        document.getElementById("usrname").value = "abc";
        document.getElementById("passwd").value = "xyz";
    }

function Submit(){
       document.getElementById('LoginButton');
       loginForm.submit();
       }

window.open("loginpage.php");

LoadTextBox();
Submit();

</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "opens a window"? do you want a new browser window or a dialog box?

Comment: @Sergio, I mean "loads the page in which I have to fill the form"!

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to put your `LoadTextBox()` and `Submit()` into `loginpage.php` since the form is present there.

2) Call `LoadTextBox()` from `onLoad` of `body`

3) Call `Submit()` from `LoadTextBox()`

Comment: what do you mean by putting LoadTextBox() and Submit() into loginpage.php?

Comment: write those functions inside `<script>` of `loginpage.php`